# quicksort, can it be made to output the first m sorted values in an N dimension array, thereby being faster than a full N sort

Tags: c, algorithm, quicksort

Quicksort is a well known algorithm, but it's complex to decipher the C (for me).  The inline version speed things up a lot http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/qsort.html‎.

However, could it be easily converted to output the first *m* samples of an *N*-element array ?

So a call that would simply stop the sort after the first *m* samples are sorted ?  I suspect not as it does a quicksort into blocks then stitches blocks together for the final output.  If I make the initial quicksort block size the size of *m* then I'm in a bad place, not taking advantage of the clever stuff in qsort.

Thanks in advance

Grog

Comment: `qsort` is a C library function. Quicksort is a sorting algorithm. I assume you're actually asking about the quicksort algorithm? The `qsort` function itself may or may not use the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: In principle, yes.  The idea is called a *partial sort*.  (See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort/) for a discussion of a relevant library function in C++).  For C, I think you'll have to find/write your own implementation.

Comment: An alternative might be a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  It's like a stack, but each time you pop it gives you the biggest value in the stack.  You could call it n times to get the n biggest values.  It should be reasonably fast, definitely faster than a full quicksort if n << N.

Comment: @Aaron McDaid When OP's `n` is significantly less than `N`, your priority queue idea is a very good solution.  I'd up-vote it.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking about the [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm?

Comment: I've made some small edits to the question, including renaming *n* to *m* - I found I was getting confused between *N* and *n*!

Comment: @chux, I wrote it up.  I got a bit carried away and included pseudocode also.  Any feedback/corrections welcome.

Comment: Gents,  That's all fantastic I will certainly be giving it a whirl.  I was initially referring to the 'qsort' library function.  I was thinking to modify the source code for this (as it is in http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/qsort.html‎ and other places) but your suggestions will be tried.

Comment: Gents, FYI, I implemented the code that you outlined, and its certainly faster than qsort for very small m from N...in my tests when n=1000000000, and m=10..it was 3 times faster but as m gets much bigger it soon slows.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [Quickselect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect), as @R.. suggested, to get the first `k` elements, then sort them. Running time is O(N) to get the elements, and O(k log k) to sort them.

However, [emperical evidence suggests](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/) that if the number of items to select (k) is less than 1% of the total number of elements (N), then using a binary heap will be faster than Quickselect followed by sort. When I had to select 200 items from a list of 2 million, the heap selection algorithm was a lot faster. See the linked blog for details.

Answer (score 1):

(Restate the question: given *N* items, find the largest *m* of them.)

A simple solution is a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  Feed all *N* items into the queue, then pop the top *m* items off the list.  Feeding the *N* items in will be O(*N log m*).  Each individual *pop* operation is *O(log m)*, so removing the top *n* items would be *O(m log m)*.

---

An in-place algorithm should be relatively straightforward.  We an array of *N* elements.  Each position in the array is numbered, with a number between 1 and N (inclusive).  For each position in the array, take its position and divide by two (rounding down if necessary), and defining that position as its *parent*.  Every position, apart from position 1, will have a parent.  And most positions (not all) will have two children.  For example:

```
node position:  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
parent:         - 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 ...
```

We want to swap the nodes until each node has a value less than (or equal to) its parent.  This will guarantee that the largest value is in position 1.  It is quite easy to reorder an array to have this form. Simply go through the nodes in order from position 1 to N, and call this function on it once:

```
void fixup_position(int x) {
   if(x==1)
      return;
   int parent_position = (x/2) ; // rounding-down where necessary
   if (data[x] > data[parent_position]) {
      swap(data[x], data[parent_position]);
      check_position(parent_position);  // note this recursive call
   }
}


for(x = 1; x <= N; ++x) {
    fixup_position(x);
}
```

(Yes, I'm counting the array with position one, not zero!  You'll have to take this account when implementing it for real.  But this is easier to understand the logic of priority queue.)

The average number of recursive calls (and therefore `swap`s) is a constant (2, if I remember correctly).  So this will be pretty quick, even with large datasets.

It's worth taking a moment to understand why this is correct.  Just before calling `fixup_position(x)`, every position up to, but not including x, are in a 'correct' state.  By 'correct' I mean that they're not fully sorted, but each node is less than its parent.  A new value is introduced (at position x), and will 'bubble up' through the queue.  You might worry that this will invalidate other positions, and their parent-child relationship, but it won't.  Only one node at a time will be in an invalid state, and it will keep bubbling up to its rightful place.

This is the O(N) step that will rearrange your array into a priority queue.

Removing the top *n* items.  After the above method, it's clear that the biggest number will be in position 1, but what about the second-biggest, and third-biggest, and so on?  What we do is we *pop* one value at a time from position 1 and then rearrange the data so that the next-biggest value is moved into position 1.  This is slightly more complex than the `fixup_position`.

```
for(int y = 1; y <= m; ++y) {
   print the number in position 1 .... it's the next biggest number
   data[1]  =  -10000000000000; // a number smaller than all your data
   fixup_the_other_way(1);  // yes, this is '1', not 'y' !
}
```

where `fixup_the_other_way` is:

```
void fixup_the_other_way(int x) {
    int child1 = 2*x;
    int child2 = 2*x+1;
    if(child1 > N)  // doesn't have any children, we're done here
        return;
    if(child2 > N) { // has one child, at position[child1]
       swap(data[x], data[child1]);
       fixup_the_other_way(child1);
       return;
    }
    // otherwise, two children, we must identify the biggest child
    int position_of_largest_child = (data[child1]>data[child2]) ? child1 : child2;
    swap(data[x], data[position_of_largest_child]);
    fixup_the_other_way(position_of_largest_child);
    return;
}
```

This means we print out the biggest remaining item, then replace that with a really small number and force it to 'bubble down' to the bottom of our data structures.

Comment: If anybody sees an error, please go ahead and make any edits yourself, I really should get on with my day job ;-)

Comment: Concept modification: If _only_ `n` smallest items are ever popped from the queue, the queue size may be limited to power(2,n).  As more than power(2,n) items are attempted to be added, the new  candidate needs to be smaller then the last element, else there is no point add it to the priority queue.  So it or the last element is tossed.  If N = 1,000,000 and n = 10, the priority queue is max size is 1023 with max depth 10.  After 1023 element added, the last (N-1023) have a worst case 10 comparisons to do.  Suspect this algorithm is O(N*n) when n <<< N and O(N*log2(N)) when n approaches N.

Comment: Gentlemen,Thank you very much for all the good stuff above.  I will certainly be giving these a go.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve the problem efficiently:-

1.> Priority Queues

Algorithm: -

1. Insert first n items into Priority Queue with max heap
2. Peek on max element to check if current element compared is less than that
3. if less delete top element and add current
4. Do steps for all N-n elements.

2.> Your Problem can be reduced to selection problem : -

Algorithm

1. Do randomized selection for nth element on N elements (O(N) in average case)
2. sort first n elements using qsort or any other efficient sorting algorithm

Using both algorithms you would get average case O(N) performance